# Vault sidecar injector permission denied only for vault enterprise

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, vault, sidecar

I am trying to explore vault enterprise but getting permission denied for sidecar when I use the vault enterprise but seems to work fine when I tried to use local vault server.

Here is the repository that contains a working example with the local vault [vault-sidecar-injector-app](https://github.com/Adiii717/vault-sidecar-injector-app)

[image]

**Vault config**

```
export VAULT_ADDR="https://vault-cluster.vault.c1c633fa-91ef-4e86-b025-4f31b3f14730.aws.hashicorp.cloud:8200"
export VAULT_NAMESPACE="admin"

#install agent
helm upgrade --install vault hashicorp/vault --set "injector.externalVaultAddr=$VAULT_ADDR"
vault auth enable kubernetes
# get certs & host
VAULT_HELM_SECRET_NAME=$(kubectl get secrets --output=json | jq -r '.items[].metadata | select(.name|startswith("vault-token-")).name')
TOKEN_REVIEW_JWT=$(kubectl get secret $VAULT_HELM_SECRET_NAME --output='go-template={{ .data.token }}' | base64 --decode)
KUBE_CA_CERT=$(kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten --output='jsonpath={.clusters[].cluster.certificate-authority-data}' | base64 --decode)
KUBE_HOST=$(kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten --output='jsonpath={.clusters[].cluster.server}')

# set Kubernetes config
vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
        token_reviewer_jwt="$TOKEN_REVIEW_JWT" \
        kubernetes_host="$KUBE_HOST" \
        kubernetes_ca_cert="$KUBE_CA_CERT" \
        issuer="https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local" \
        disable_iss_validation="true" \
        disable_local_ca_jwt="true"


vault auth enable approle
# create admin policy
vault policy write admin admin-policy.hcl
vault write auth/approle/role/admin policies="admin"
vault read auth/approle/role/admin/role-id
# generate secret
vault write -f  auth/approle/role/admin/secret-id
#Enable KV
vault secrets enable -version=2 kv
```

I can see the role and policy
[image]

**Admin policy**

Here is the admin policy for the enterprise

```
path "*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list", "sudo"]
}
```

**Deploy Script for helm**

here is the deploy script, tried `hcp-root` root policy but no luck

```sh
RELEASE_NAME=demo-managed
NAMESPACE=default
ENVIRONMENT=develop
export role_id="f9782a53-823e-2c08-81ae-abc"
export secret_id="1de3b8c5-18c7-60e3-24ca-abc"
export VAULT_ADDR="https://vault-cluster.vault.c1c633fa-91ef-4e86-b025-4f31b3f14730.aws.hashicorp.cloud:8200"
export VAULT_TOKEN=$(vault write -field="token"  auth/approle/login role_id="${role_id}" secret_id="${secret_id}")
vault write auth/kubernetes/role/${NAMESPACE}-${RELEASE_NAME} bound_service_account_names=${RELEASE_NAME} bound_service_account_namespaces=${NAMESPACE} policies=hcp-root ttl=1h
helm upgrade --install $RELEASE_NAME ../helm-chart --set environment=$ENVIRONMENT --set nameOverride=$RELEASE_NAME
```

also tried with root token

```sh
RELEASE_NAME=demo-managed
NAMESPACE=default
ENVIRONMENT=develop
vault write auth/kubernetes/role/${NAMESPACE}-${RELEASE_NAME} bound_service_account_names=${RELEASE_NAME} bound_service_account_namespaces=${NAMESPACE} policies=hcp-root ttl=1h
helm upgrade --install $RELEASE_NAME ../helm-chart --set environment=$ENVIRONMENT --set nameOverride=$RELEASE_NAME
```

**Sidecar config**

With namespace annotation, as my understanding namespace is required

> vault.hashicorp.com/namespace - configures the Vault Enterprise namespace to be used when requesting secrets from Vault.

https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/injector/annotations

```
vault.hashicorp.com/namespace : "admin"
```

**Error**

```
  | Error making API request.
  |
  | URL: PUT https://vault-cluster.vault.c1c633fa-91ef-4e86-b025-4f31b3f14730.aws.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/admin/auth/kubernetes/login
  | Code: 403. Errors:
  |
  | * permission denied
```

Without namespace annotation getting below error

```
  | URL: PUT https://vault-cluster.vault.c1c633fa-91ef-4e86-b025-4f31b3f14730.aws.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
  | Code: 400. Errors:
  |
  | * missing client token
```

Even enabling debug logs `vault.hashicorp.com/log-level : "debug"` does not help me with this error,  any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Also tried
https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404389946387-Kubernetes-auth-method-Permission-Denied-error

So seems like I am missing something very specific to the vault enterprise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally able to resolve the weird issue with vault, posting as an answer might help someone else.

The only thing that I missed to understand the flow between vault server, sidecar, and Kubernetes.

[image]

Kubernetes should be reachable to vault enterprise for Token review API calls. As you can see the when sidecar makes a request to the vault, then the vault enterprise server performs a token review API call.

> Use the /config endpoint to configure **Vault to talk to Kubernetes**. Use kubectl cluster-info to validate the **Kubernetes host address** and TCP port.

https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/kubernetes

```
  | Error making API request.
  |
  | URL: PUT https://vault-cluster.vault.c1c633fa-91ef-4e86-b025-4f31b3f14730.aws.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/admin/auth/kubernetes/login
  | Code: 403. Errors:
  |
  | * permission denied
   backoff=2.99s
```

This error does not indicate it has a connectivity issue but this also happens when the vault is not able to communicate with the Kubernetes cluster.

## Kube Host

```
vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
        token_reviewer_jwt="$TOKEN_REVIEW_JWT" \
        kubernetes_host="$KUBE_HOST" \
        kubernetes_ca_cert="$KUBE_CA_CERT" \
        issuer="https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local"
```

`KUBE_HOST` should be reachable for vault enterprise for tokenreview process.

So for the vault to communicate with our cluster, we need a few changes.

```
minikube start --apiserver-ips=14.55.145.30 --vm-driver=none
```

Now update the `vaul-config.sh` file

```
KUBE_HOST=$(kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten --output='jsonpath={.clusters[].cluster.server}')
```

change this to

```
KUBE_HOST=""https://14.55.145.30:8443/"
```

No manual steps, for the first time configuration run

```
./vault-config.sh
```

and for the rest of the deployment in your CI/CD you can use

```
./vault.sh
```

Each release has only been able to access its own secrets.

Furter details can be found [start-minikube-in-ec2](https://github.com/Adiii717/vault-sidecar-injector-app/blob/main/README.md#start-minikube-in-ec2)

TLDR,

**Note: Kubernetes cluster should be reachable to vault enterprise for authentication, so vault enterprise would not able to communicate with your local minikube cluster. Better to test it out on EC2**

Answer (score 1):

When you have set the Kubernetes auth into the vault you have used the

```
vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
        token_reviewer_jwt="$TOKEN_REVIEW_JWT" \
        kubernetes_host="$KUBE_HOST" \
        kubernetes_ca_cert="$KUBE_CA_CERT" \
        issuer="https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local" \
        disable_iss_validation="true" \
        disable_local_ca_jwt="true"
```

you have mentioned

```
issuer="https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local" \
```

it's HTTP and looks like running the local K8s server, not sure vault will be able to access this endpoint or not.

Did you try sending auth at this endpoint bypassing the Token & CA cert?

Your vault is able to connect and authenticate over the internet of your local cluster?

also i have faced this weird issue, with vault i used configure using both ways **CLI** and **UI** then it was working for me while in a single way it was giving error of `permission denied`.

Comment: I do not think the vault server communicates with the Kubernetes cluster, it's the sidecar the managed inside Kubernetes stuff and the sidecar communicates with vault server.
second it should return timeout instead of permission denied ?

Comment: Vault agent: Auto-Auth - Automatically authenticate to Vault and manage the token renewal process for locally-retrieved dynamic secrets.
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/agent-kubernetes?in=vault/kubernetes

Comment: Thanks man, finally figure it out, its the kube_host that play the role.

Comment: Glad to hear that you resolve issue.

Comment: yeah it was really weird , I have to reproduce the issue by running vault in docker and then minikube, and then I figure out the vault server logs, its not able to communicate with Kubernetes API.
btw I added each everything in the repo with zero configuration

Comment: Great...! thanks for sharing details that might be helpful to others, checked that repo updated 2-3 hours back with the handy shell script. i have also documente locally but i think cant attach the document in the answer, it's also the same with minimalist config.